# How to find substring in a datframe from a list to create a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to create a new column based on substring matched with the list.

I have 2 lists like this:

```
positive_list = ['good', 'high', 'nice', 'fair']
negative_list = ['bad', 'worst', 'low']
```

I have dataframe like this:

```
id     text     
1      #bad_boy_here
2      #nice_but_low
3      high jump
4      what is good
```

I need to create two extra columns negative and positive

```
id     text                      positive               negative
1      #bad_boy_here             NaN                    Neg
2      #nice_but_low             Pos                    Neg
3      high jump                 Pos                    NaN
4      what is good              Pos                    NaN
```

I was thinking to use `np.where` but not getting the desired output and not sure how I can use the list in np.where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), here is not use `np.nan` but `None` for avoid `NaN` converting to string `'nan'`:

```
df = df.assign(positive = np.where(df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(positive_list), case=False), 'Pos', None),
               negative = np.where(df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(negative_list), case=False), 'Neg', None))
print (df)
   id           text positive negative
0   1  #bad_boy_here     None      Neg
1   2  #nice_but_low      Pos      Neg
2   3      high jump      Pos     None
3   4   what is good      Pos     None
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possibility to neglect case sensitivity? I can't detect that when the first letter is capital